# ¿Por qué la palabra "huida" no lleva tilde?

Tags: acentuación, diptongos

No entiendo por qué la palabra [**"huida"**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=l6CJzmr9ZDXX2pXnH11Y%7CPDmfcXgODDXX21o6nnfxhi) no lleva tilde. Si "caída" la lleva, ¿por qué esta no si al fin y al cabo suenan igual?

Veamos si analizo bien la situación.

- La palabra se separa en sílabas como sigue: `/hu-i-da/`
- Dado que /ui/ es diptongo, para convertirlo en hiato debemos añadir la tilde.

Como posible explicación, leo en [Acentuación del idioma español - diptongos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acentuaci%C3%B3n_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol#Diptongos)

> En algunas palabras, estas combinaciones vocálicas a veces se
>   pronuncian incorrectamente como hiatos (por ejemplo «fluir», a veces
>   se pronuncia como hiato /flu-ir/), pero a efectos de acentuación
>   gráfica son siempre diptongos.

Por lo que mi hipótesis es: ¿será que se pronuncia `/hui-da/` y no `/hu-i-da/`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para efectos de acentuación gráfica (es decir, en cuestiones de escribir o no una tilde), se considera la combinación *ui* siempre diptongo independiente de la realización verdadera sea esa /wi/ /uj/ o /u.i/.

Eso es porque si tildamos la *i* en una palabra como *huida*, todavía tenemos un diptongo (*u* débil con *i* ahora fuerte).  En una palabra como *caída*, la tilde rompe el diptongo porque ahora tenemos una *a* (siempre fuerte) y una *i* hecha fuerte con la tilde.  Dos vocales fuertes forman hiato y se pronuncian en sílabas diferentes.

Simplemente hay que memorizar la silabificación de estas palabras.  No solo ocurre, de hecho, con palabras con *ui*.  Si tenemos una combinación diptongada en que no recae el acento de la palabra, es imposible saber por la escritura si es diptongo verdadero (normal) o un llamado hiato excepcional, hecho más complicado por diferencias dialectales.

Yo pronuncio la palabra *enviar* en tres sílabas con hiato excepcional /em.bi'ar/ como es característica de la pronunciación peninsular.  Pero en partes de Latinoamérica es fácil encontrar con diptongo /em'bjar/.  No es posible marcar con tilde porque el acento tiene que recaer en la última sílaba, tildando la *i* para hacer hiato pondría el acento en el interior de la palabra: /em'bi.ar/ que no tiene sentido en la mayoría de las formas pero sí en algunas formas del presente y del imperativo.  Lo mismo ocurre en palabras como *evaluar*, etcétera.

Comment: No obstante, sería por lo menos posible marcar con diéresis, ¿no? _Envïar_ sería menos ambiguo. Aún en casos como _pingüino_ (con ⟨g⟩ antes), poderíamos desambiguar todas las posibles pronunciaciones combinando la tilde y la diéresis: _pinguino_ es [piŋ.ˈɡi.no], _pingüino_ es [piŋ.ˈɡwi.no], _pingúino_ sería [piŋ.ˈɡuj.no], _pingúïno_ sería [piŋ.ˈɡu.i.no] y _pingüíno_ sería [piŋ.ɡu.ˈi.no].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet así es, más o menos, como se hace en la poesía, sobre todo cuando la métrica demanda que un diptongo (como en *guapo*) se realice en dos monoptongos (güapo es /gu'a.po/), pero el problema es más bien que según país puede que haya o no el hiato y la idea de la RAE ha sido minimizar las diferencias ortográficas entre regiones (por ejemplo, *guion* puede ser palabra mono- o bisilábica, antes de 2010, la gente bisilábica escribía *guión*). La realidad también es que poca gente notará la diferencia cuando se encuentra el diptongo/hiato excepcional en sílabas no acentuadas.

Comment: Claro, claro. Sólo porque se _puede_ hacer alguna cosa no quiere decir que se _debe_ hacer. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet exactamente. Y es una cuestión (precisión frente a generalización) que se hace para todo sistema ortográfico. Si lees algunas de las primeras ortografías de la RAE, es interesante notar que solo es ahora que estamos más o menos llegando al estado ortográfico que quería/imaginaba en el siglo XVIII. Era alucinante ver la lógica con que ha desarrollado el sistema en español, aunque cada paso u otro por sí solo puede parece raro.

Comment: Caramba, qué caso tan curioso. Así, la tilde deja de ponerse porque no aportaría nada, así que no hay manera de conocer cómo debe pronunciarse. Al ser una palabra llana terminada en vocal, no hay tilde. Dos cosas: ¿es entonces correcto pronunciarlo com /hu-i-da/? ¿no se ha planteado la academía introducir algún tipo de acentuación para clarificar la pronunciación en estos casos, tal y como sugiere @JanusBahsJacquet? En catalán, por ejemplo, esto se resuelve con la diéresis: _fruït_, _fruïció_.

Comment: @fedorqui creo que podrás escuchar ambas formas. Incluso si dices /u'i.da/, igual a lo ocurre en palabras como *toalla*, fácilmente se diptongará en en habla. Es más por la variación e inestabilidad panhispánicas (e incluso para un hablante) de la *ui* átona que estas cosas no se marcan (opino yo, al menos).

Answer (score -2):

Actualmente, aunque el conjunto de la vocal "u" con la "i", tenga una pronunciación más fuerte en la "i" y se convierta en un supuesto hiato (como pasa con "caída", la RAE ha impuesto que este conjunto se tome como diptongo, o sea, como una misma por así decirlo "letra", así que en la palabra "huida", se leería hui-da y no hu-í-da, como muchos quisiéramos que fuera. Por lo tanto, las conocidas reglas de tildado aplicarían (hablo de las palabras agudas, graves, etc.) y no estaríamos hablando del tildado por cuestiones de hiato (Ej: Caida).

Te dejo ejemplos para que entiendas mejor esta regla:

Ej.

- huir
- huimos
- hui (Se toma como una sola sílaba, aunque realmente se escuchen dos)
- oí (Es una palabra aguda y con dos vocales, y no incluye la conjunción "uir" que se considera diptongo)
- oído
- oír (Aquí tampoco está "uir", por lo que podemos hacer el hiato y no el diptongo)