# ¿Es correcto escribir "cuídate"? ¿dónde se debe poner la tilde? ¿y el acento?

Tags: pronunciación, acentuación

Hace poco pregunté [¿Por qué la palabra "huida" no lleva tilde?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14855/1674) y [guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/4182/guifa) dio una [fantástica explicación](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14857/1674) al respecto: *ui* es siempre diptongo, independientemente de si una de las dos vocales se acentúa. Por tanto, la palabra *huida* es llana terminada en vocal, luego no lleva tilde.

Ahora me ha sobrevenido otra cuestión parecida, pero no igual: ¿lleva la palabra "cuidate" tilde? Si es así, ¿dónde? ¿Y cómo se pronuncia?

He aquí mi hipótesis: debería llevar tilde en la *í* (**cuídate**), pues es esdrújula (la tónica es la antepenúltima sílaba). Sin embargo, yo particularmente pronuncio la *u* más fuerte que la *i*, lo que me hace dudar si la tilde debe ser en una vocal o la otra.

¿Cómo puedo saberlo? ¿Tenemos alguna manera de saberlo si no es memorizando? guifa comentaba que:

> Simplemente hay que memorizar la silabificación de estas palabras. No
>   solo ocurre, de hecho, con palabras con ui. Si tenemos una combinación
>   diptongada en que no recae el acento de la palabra, es imposible saber
>   por la escritura si es diptongo verdadero (normal) o un llamado hiato
>   excepcional, hecho más complicado por diferencias dialectales.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La respuesta es también «por convención»:

> Este diptongo no lleva tilde, salvo
>    cuando se trata de palabras agudas (acabadas en vocal, *-n* o *-s*)
>   o esdrújulas; en este caso, el diptongo *ui*  lleva acento en la *-i* (*-uí*): *benjuí, cuídate*.
>
> (Fuente: Departamento de español urgente de la agencia EFE: 
>   Diccionario de español urgente. 
>   Madrid: Ediciones S.M., 2000, p. 161.)

Vía [Hispanoteca](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Diptongo%20ui%20-%20iu.htm), en la que aclaran:

> La combinación de la vocal cerrada *i* con la vocal cerrada *u* se considerarán siempre diptongos a efectos de acentuación gráfica, aunque se pueden pronunciar como hiatos o como diptongos. Para la acentuación seguirán las normas generales y en caso de llevar tilde, ésta se pondrá sobre la segunda vocal.

Entiendo que se ha decidido optar por esa norma aunque pueda no ajustarse a la pronunciación del acento en según que dialectos, precisamente por existir esa disparidad de pronunciaciones consideradas variaciones y no incorrecciones.

Comment: Por aclarar más, igual que tú dices que tiendes a pronunciar kúj-da-te, hay gente que tenderá al cu-í-da-te o al cú-i-da-te. Yo, personalmente, tiendo al kwí-da-te. La colocación de la tilde la veo como una solución para que podamos atenernos todos a algo invariable, aunque sea de compromiso.

Comment: las formas /'**kuj**.da.te/, /'**kwi**.da.te/ y /ku'**i**.da.te/ todas me suenan posibles (yo con la segunda), pero /'**ku**.i.da.te/ me parece poco posible (tampoco lo descarto porque siempre será posible que en algun lugar que alguien lo haga, pero violaría algunos principios del sistema flexional español)

Comment: @guifa ha sido un mero ejercicio de combinatoria sin tener en cuenta la fonotáctica. No sé ni dónde se diría cada combinación, ni con qué frecuencia... Ni si se diría en absoluto. Tendría que haber dicho «habrá» más que «hay».

Comment: Ah vale, pensaba que decías que lo habías escuchado en algún momento (que conste, no era para corregirte ni nada, solo que me habría dado una verdadera –e interesante– sorpresa saber la existencia de tal pronunciación)

Answer (score 3):

Es un poco tarde, ya se aceptó la respuesta... pero creo que sería mejor un depende. Según a quien se refiera, cuidate puede o no llevar tilde.

Si **tú** me pides a mi que me **cuide**, **cuídate** es esdrújula, debe llevar tilde y está bien escrito. Ahora bien, si yo te pido a **vos** que te **cuidés**, **cuidate** está bien escrito al ser palabra llana o grave, sin importar el diptongo de la primera sílaba, así pues según con quién hables o a quien le escribás, llevará o no tilde.

Así pues, tenga cuidado para poner la tilde