# ¿Cuáles son los verbos en participio pasado que llevan tilde?

Tags: verbos, acentuación, participio

El día de hoy me encontraba leyendo y vi que la palabrá ***[caído](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dYQa6m)*** llevaba tilde. Mi percepción era que todos los verbos en participio pasado **no llevaban tilde**, ahora entiendo que eso es falso.

Lo anterior me lleva a preguntar, ¿cuáles son los verbos en participio pasado que llevan tilde?

Tomando como ejemplo, el verbo ***[traído](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aFcGj2k)*** también lleva acento, no obstante, ***[huido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KmEdpit)*** no lleva.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué la palabra “huida” no lleva tilde?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14855/1674)

Comment: De todos modos, creo que consultar _qué verbos en pasado participio llevan tilde_ tiene una connotación como de que la acentuación depende de la categoría gramatical de una palabra. Pero no, las reglas de acentuación son transparentes a esto: llevan tilde los verbos en pasado participio que deben llevar tilde según las reglas generales de ortografía.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los verbos con participio acentuado son aquellos que lo hacen según [las reglas de la ortografía](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=tilde). En el caso de los verbos que mencionas:

- *Caído* y *traído* llevan tilde porque el acento cae en un hiato constituido por una vocal abierta átona más una vocal cerrada tónica. En estos casos la vocal cerrada tónica siempre lleva tilde.
- *Huido* no lleva tilde porque el acento cae en un diptongo (dos vocales cerradas), y en estos casos se siguen las normas generales. Al ser palabra llana acaba en vocal, no lleva tilde.

Sería complicado hacer un listado exhaustivo de todos los verbos que cumplen con tu requisito, así que lo mejor es simplemente conocer las reglas de acentuación y seguirlas. El enlace de arriba te lleva al artículo sobre la tilde en el DPD, que constituye un resumen del conjunto completo de reglas, que [puedes encontrar](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QnSfjOOzJxiTQvmz) en la *Ortografía 2010*.

Comment: Vale decir, llevan tilde todos los participios terminados en -aído, -eído y -oído.

Comment: @Rodrigo parece que así es. La única posible excepción que he encontrado es "ahíto", que podría considerarse un participio irregular de "ahitar" (aunque el participio es "ahitado", en diccionarios antiguos se considera "ahíto" y "ahitado" como la misma cosa, y etimológicamente parece provenir de un participio).

Comment: @Rodrigo Efectivamente, no se contempla la *h* a la hora de determinar donde poner los tildes, da igual que sea uno de los (muy) pocos dialectos que preservan la pronunciación aspirada.  Así que sería, *-aído*, *-ahído*, *-eído*, *-ehído*, *-oído*, *-ohído*, pero si hay algún verbo que termine en *-[aeo]h[ei]r*, lo ignoro.

Comment: @guifa "[Retraher](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WJQp3v2)" existe pero es un sustantivo. Con las demás combinaciones no aparece nada en el DRAE (que tiene una opción de buscar palabras que terminan en el término de búsqueda). Solo en el de Autoridades aparece "retraher" como verbo, que tendría el participio "retrahído" (forma que aparece en [textos del CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?MfcISAPICommand=buscar&tradQuery=1&destino=1&texto=retrah%EDdo&autor=&titulo=&ano1=&ano2=&medio=1000&pais=1000&tema=1000), el más reciente de 1745).

Comment: CarlosAlejo muchas gracias por la aclaración, sería buena idea que complementaras la respuesta con el comentario de @Rodrigo ya que con eso también queda más clara la respuesta, y al igual, también poner tu respuesta al comentario ya mencionado. Nuevamente, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Yo también me confundo con los participios en "-ido". El problema para mí no son las reglas gramaticales, sino que al hablar pronunciamos como diptongos o hiatos palabras que no lo son. Por ejemplo, "aeropuerto": "ae" lo pronunciamos como diptongo cuando es un hiato porque las vocales abiertas (a e o) nunca pueden formar diptongo.

Las palabras, "huido" y "hui" no las pronunciamos como un diptongo, sino como un hiato (es decir, separamos las vocales), a diferencia de ¡Uy!, que lo pronunciamos como el diptongo que es. La regla de que "huido"  es un diptongo sospecho que tiene que ver con algo que no se explica, y es que los diptongos se acentúan todos en la vocal abierta (a, e, o). Por eso "hay" y "piano" son diptongos, aunque pronunciamos "pi-a-no" (separamos las vocales) y no "pia-no", como en italiano.

Las reglas gramaticales no dan cuenta, en este caso, de la realidad del habla (en mi opinión)

Comment: Me parece muy interesante tu reflexión. No soy experto, pero sospecho que tienes razón.